# Dual workspaces, One monitor

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm currently using Linux Mint, and have a single 24 inch monitor. Does anyone know of an application that will allow two workspaces to be viewed \ used at the same time? I know of window managers like i3, but I'm searching for a desktop "workspace viewer" that would allow full screen flash video on one side of my monitor and a terminal window or other program on the other side. i3 and similar takes the full monitor when a video is put into full screen.

Comment: Is remote desktop an option?

Comment: Would prefer a local option, if there is one.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but if you put the application in fullscreen mode (e.g. F11 on Chrome) and then toggle fullscreen using i3 ($mod+f by default), the application will think it is still running fullscreen but will be in a window. You can then place the "fullscreen" video and any other program side by side, or in any other configuration. I use this for many kinds of applications and almost always works (evince has been the only exception so far).